# Can you use picking with animated mesh?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I askes a question on gamedev about picking.  The guy said that you can't really use picking with animated mesh...  Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. Picking is usually done in one frame and in that time, your animated mash is static exactly same as static mash... 
I have implemented that kind of picking, so - It is possible without any kind of problem

Comment: Well... I have done picking with static mesh with no problem but now i'm doing it with animated mesh but it won't work do you have to change anything in it? I also have question about my picking function